# How to share data between model and view?

Tags: multithreading, mvvm, data-modeling

I'm currently working on redesigning an application which is building a model from input data, and displaying that data to the user. The current system has a thread for building the model, a thread for building a visualization of the model, and a thread which displays the visualization. The problem I have is that pointers are passed between the modeling and visualization threads - in order to make the threads safe, all objects in the model have to have a mutex. This means there are thousands of mutexes active in the system, with lots of stalls as both threads contend for resources.

So, given that those three threads will exist, what is the best way to share data between the modeling and visualization threads in a manner which is efficient and thread safe? Some of the data structures are large and will change every cycle of the modeling thread, so I'm somewhat loath to make a copy of the data every pass.

EDIT:

The total latency through the system we're hoping for is to have ~100ms from receiving a message to the display showing the change in the display. We would like it to be faster if possible, but more importantly we need it to be consistent - right now we see huge variability in the cycle times, due to the mutex contention. The data moving from modeling to visualization are dominated by 2D height maps - ~18000 cells worth of data. The actual number of cells updated in model update is significantly less though - perhaps only a few hundred.

Comment: For a meaningful answer you would have to give at least some figures for the update rate of the visualization, its complexity, the size of the data that would have to be copied, stuff like that. Otherwise this would be pure guesswork on our part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big fan of the message posting/message pump architecture. This the main method that MFC/Win32 provides to communicate data between threads. This architecture is event driven off of thread messages, so when the receiving thread is processing a thread message, it is processing data explicitly newed for the communication between threads (see example below).

You could implement this yourself, and localize the locking to each thread's individual list of thread messages. So when one thread wants to message another thread you do roughly the following

```
PostThreadMessage(msg, void* param, int paramSize)
{
    lock(msgQueueLock);

    // may wish to copy param
    char paramCpy = malloc
    msgQueue.Queue(msg, pparam, paramSize); 

    unlock(msgQueueLock);
}
```

then the main loop of any thread is just

```
// thread's msg pump
while (1)
{
    // can also use condition var to wait for queue to change...
    lock(msgQueueLock);
    HandleMsgLocally(msgQueue.Deque())
    unlock(msgQueueLock);
}
```

Anyway, getting back to MVC, if something changes in your model, it can post to your view to update a specific field as such:

```
// Well known msg name
int msgName = MODEL_FIELD_A_UPDATED

...

void Model::UpdateFieldA(int newVal)
{
    int* valToCommunicate = new int(newVal)
    PostThreadMessage(MODEL_FIELD_A_UPDATED, valToCommunicate, sizeof(int))
}


...
void HandleMsgLocally(...void * param,)
{
    if (msg == MODEL_FIELD_A_UPDATED)
    {
       int* val = reinterpret_cast<int*>(param);
       //... process param
       delete val;
    }
}
```

The advantages are you localize your locking. This is huge. Also so long as the param's are understood to be explicitely new'd by the sender and deleted by the receiver, you don't have to worry about accessing shared memory.

There are many disadvantages to this, latency being one. If you need to know right away that something changed, then you would need to actually make that shared data and think about the best locking scheme.  If you truly need a global state that can get updated at any time from multiple directions, a singleton is fine in this case in my book.  This design is really mostly suited for data that goes one direction, you can get into race conditions. You may also be able to, however, implement locking getters for inspection by one thread from another, but to set the value you have to post. There's lots of variables to think about, but hopefully this might help you. Also, you can forget to delete the params in the message.

**Update based on Edit**
Based on your info, depending on the amount of data, posting could very well work. Profiling your code would be important. If I were you I'd play with some proof of concept and switch to using condition variables to manage synchronicity. If you are on a Windows platform, definitely use their message pump.

Answer (score 2):

I already commented on the difficulty of answering this in any meaningful way without more detailed data from you, but here are two tips anyway:

- Don't update the visualization more often than necessary. Depending on the complexity of your visualization you should limit the display to maybe 3 or 5 updates per second, so if your modelling thread progresses much faster, then don't display every iteration. You could either have the visualization thread request new data every x milliseconds, or you could have the modelling thread request a new visualization after it has finished and enough time has passed since the last visualization.
- Don't use locking if you can avoid it. The use of shared pointers to immutable data eliminates a lot of thread contention, as you will not need to lock the objects (all access is read-only). With a fine-grained class design you will also limit the need to copy data to those parts that really change from one modelling loop to the next. This may however need a lot of changes to your current design. I have found this to be really worthwhile, though.

**Edit:** After your edit I would even more recommend to eliminate locking as much as possible, given that you want to display a lot of data as fast as possible, but change only maybe 5% of the total data.

If you modify the algorithm from changing a cell to creating a new cell based on the modified data, and you do not modify your model at all, but create a new model by only copying the smart pointers to unmodified cells and creating new cell objects for the rest, then you will not need any lock on any of the several thousands of objects. The completed model can be passed to the visualization thread, and a new model can be created immediately. Similarly for the visualization thread and the object it creates from the model - it can be passed to the GUI thread, and a new object be created from the then current model. Some cells will be part of several models, some cells will be part of only one model. Objects for creating the visualization and rendering to the output display can share the cells as well. The smart pointers will make sure that cells are properly freed when the last reference to them is removed - whichever thread this happens in.

The only locking that will be left in your program is one top-level lock per thread to synchronize access to the current model (or other, similar top-level objects). Since the performed operations will be very short, latency should no longer be an issue. In addition to that this design will make maximum use of multiple processors or cores, at the cost of slightly more memory consumption and more CPU cycles spent. This is however the best way to make software perform better on current and future hardware, which is becoming increasingly parallel.